# In aggregate graph in jmeter how to add custom percentage line like 90%, 95%, 80% etc

Tags: graph, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In aggregate graph in jmeter how to add custom percentage line like 90%, 95%, 80% etc

I want this custom percentage line in aggregate report and graph both.

[image: What this to be customized]

I found an screenshot with multiple % lines in jmeter's documentation but didn't get the way to customized it

[image: Got a reference screenshot with multiple %line]

Answer (score 2):

If what you want to do is replace one of percentiles (90, 95, 99) by other values, then in user.properties modify:

> aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
>
> aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
>
> aggregate_rpt_pct3=99

Then this percentile will appear in screen